# jQuery check if select field changed

Tags: jquery

I would like to make a jQuery check if a select field was changed. If it changes, set an alert message (has changed), if returned to default, set another alert message (default value).

```
$('select').on('change',function () {
    var isDirty = false;

    $('select').each(function () { 
        var $e = $(this);      
        if (!$e[0].options[$e[0].selectedIndex].defaultSelected) {
        isDirty = true;
        }    
    });

    if(isDirty == true) { 
        alert("has changed");
    } else {
        alert("default value");          
    }
});
```

Please advise if this is the proper way.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't need inner `each` loop. Plus `$(this)[0]` can be optimised to just `this`:

```js
$('select').on('change', function () {
        
    var isDirty = !this.options[this.selectedIndex].defaultSelected;

    if (isDirty) {
        alert("has changed");
    } else {
        alert("default value");
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="" id="">
    <option value="1">Label 1</option>
    <option value="2" selected>Label 2</option>
    <option value="3">Label 3</option>
    <option value="4">Label 4</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thank you for your clear answer. Regarding to `each` loop, if I want to check all the select fields available in a form, it won't be needed? This is a newbie question :)

Comment: `$('select').on('change', ...)` already handles all selectboxes (it uses each internally).

Answer (score 1):

I would do something like:

HTML:

```
<select data-default="one" id="the-select">
  <option>one</option>
  <option>two</option>
</select>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#the-select').change(function() {
    var changed = $(this).val() != $(this).data('default');
    alert(changed ? 'changed' : 'not changed');
});
```